# Jobs are executed many times on an AWS worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, worker, rails-activejob

I'm performing some jobs on an AWS worker environment. I can't get why but for some reason my job is executed many times. I can say that because I save my job in the database and I saw it in a state `running`, then `completed`, and then `running` again. Even though I launched it just one time. My application is built in Ruby on Rails, I'm using active_job and the gem [active_elastic_job](https://github.com/tawan/active-elastic-job) because I take advantage of elastic beanstalk. Anyone have any idea? I can provide all the info you want.

Comment: Any chance that your workers are driven by messages in SQS and you've neglected to delete the SQS message at the end of processing, causing the message to be made visible again in SQS and hence processed repeatedly?

Comment: Mmmm, that's interesting. I mean, it's possible considering I don't do anything at the end of the processing.

Comment: I don't work much with EB workers but this blog post might be valuable: http://blog.brianbeach.com/2016/11/elastic-beanstalk-worker-environment.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read :)